# Hive Concatenation

Tags: sql, hive, concatenation

I have the following data

```
name  location
Scott Toronto
James Alaska
Tiger London
James Alaska
```

I want to concatenate the name and the location. It should return a single column with distinct values with the order by location and then name.

I tried with the following which didn't work.

```
select distinct concat(name,' ', location) from table1 order by location,name;
select distinct concat_ws(' ',name,location) from table1 order by location, name;
```

Then I tried with the following

```
select distinct name from (select name,location,concat_ws(' ',name,location)name from table1 order by location,name)x;
```

This is returning distinct values however not in the desired sort order.

Please let me know what could be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "didn't work" means.  But your first version would just about work with `group by`.  This is what you want:

```
select concat(name, ' ', location)
from table1
group by name, location
order by location, name;
```

You may need to write this as:

```
select nl
from (select concat(name, ' ', location) as nl, location, name
      from table1
      group by name, location
     ) nl
order by location, name;
```

This does have one issue -- ambiguity -- if you have "A B" in `name` and "C" in location in one row and then "A" and "B C" in another row then the concatenated value is the same.  But the above would return that as two rows.

To fix that potential problem (which seems unlikely), you can instead use:

```
select concat(name, ' ', location) as nl
from table1
group by nl
order by min(location), min(name);
```

This works with `group by` because you can use expressions in the `order by`.  It does not work with `select distinct` because neither the columns nor aggregations on them are available after the `select distinct`.

Comment: select concat(name, ' ', location) from table1 group by name, location order by location, name;
This didn't work, it returned "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:78 Invalid table alias or column reference 'location': (possible column names are: _c0)"

Comment: select concat(name, ' ', location) as nl from table1 group by nl order by min(location), min(name);
This also didnt work, it throw the error.. "FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:62 Invalid table alias or column reference 'nl': (possible column names are: name, location, somecol

Comment: I tried with different ways, it is not accepting ORDER BY clause

Comment: @Onlydocs . . . Hive seems to have some very arcane parsing limitations.  I added a version with a subquery that should work.

Comment: I tried all possible ways, No luck. Still the same error. It's working till GROUP BY but it's not working with the ORDER BY clause only.  I am using "Hive 1.1.0" in ClouderaVM 5.10.0.

Comment: The below is worked
````
select concat(name,' ',location) from(select distinct name,location from table1 order by location, name)x;
````

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to say Thanks :)